# Charge Conjugation for $SU(N)$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, group-theory, charge-conjugation

For $SU(2)$ the charge conjugation operator $C$ reads explicitly

$$ C \Psi = i \sigma_2 \Psi^\star ,$$

where $\sigma_2$ is a Pauli matrix. What is the generalized charge conjugation for $SU(N)$?

Comment: Look at [Cliffords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-dimensional_gamma_matrices) first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Representation of $SU(2)$ is pseudo-real. Which means, if $\mathbf{[2]}$ and $\mathbf{[\bar{2}]}$ are the fundamental and anti-fundamental representation of $SU(2)$, then there exists an anti-symmetric matrix $\cal{C}$, which connect both of them, as $\cal{C}\mathbf{[2]}\cal{C}^{-1}=\mathbf{[\bar{2}]}$. Another way of saying this, both $\mathbf{[2]}$ and $\mathbf{[\bar{2}]}$ are connected by a similarity transformation. Where, one can identify $\cal{C}=i\sigma^{2}$.

But this result can not extended for $SU(N)$ where $N>2$. Its a theorem: There exist no matrix like $\cal{C}$ which connect fundamental representation $\textbf{N}$ of $SU(N)$ with anti-fundamental representation $\bar{N}$. Therefore all representations of $SU(N)$ for $N>2$ are complex.

Comment: Is it possible to define such a charge conjugation matrix $\mathcal{C}$ in other representations of SU(2) other than fundamental representation?